# Query a value from one table and use that value as table to query sub values

Tags: database, postgresql

I have multiple tables in PostgreSQL named `a`, `b` and `data_X_XX` where `X` can be any value.
`data_X_XX` contains these columns: `azimuth`, `skew` and `tilt`.
`b` contains these columns: `a_id`, `data_table_name`, `serial_no`. `data_table_name` will contain the names of tables `data_X_XX`.
`a` contains these columns: `id`, `name`, `location`.
Now, I want to select the values of `azimuth` from `data_X_XX` and display them as:

```
a.name, b.serial_no, data_X_XX.azimuth
```

I have tried `select azimuth from b.data_table_name where b.data_table_name='data_X_XX'`, and `select azimuth from (select data_table_name from b)`; this all returns an error.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the table names for `data_x_xx` are dynamic, you will have to use dynamic sql. And for the sake of being able to return it in a table structure, I'll put it in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
    RETURNS TABLE (name TEXT, serial_no ???, azimuth ???) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
        'SELECT a.name, b.serial_no, (SELECT azimuth FROM ' || b.data_table_name || ')
        FROM a
        JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id';
END
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Replace `???` with the actual data type.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue. Although, I had to make changes according to the table requirements. cheers!!